# jqGrid formatCell event doesn't fire

Tags: jqgrid

For some reason (unknown to me) the event 'formatCell' doesn't fire (no alert message shown). see code below:

```
$("#jqgrid").jqGrid({
            datatype: "json",

            colNames: ['CurrecncyID', 'Currency', 'Value', 'Calculated', 'Value', '%', 'Calculated'],
            colModel: [
                        { name: 'CurrecncyID', index: 'CurrecncyID', hidden: true, width: 40 },
                        { name: 'CurrencyName', index: 'CurrencyName', width: 150 },
                        { name: 'FullPrice', index: 'FullPrice', width: 100, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: priceCheck }, editable: true, align: 'right', formatter: priceFormatter },
                        { name: 'CalcFullPrice', index: 'CalcFullPrice', width: 100, align: 'right', formatter: priceFormatter },
                        { name: 'ActualPrice', index: 'ActualPrice', width: 100, editrules: { custom: true, custom_func: priceCheck }, editable: true, align: 'right', formatter: priceFormatter },
                        { name: 'Precent', index: 'Precent', width: 100, align: 'right', formatter: 'integer', formatoptions: { prefix: "% "} },
                        { name: 'CalcActualPrice', index: 'CalcActualPrice', width: 100, align: 'right', formatter: priceFormatter },
                    ],
            onSelectRow: function (id) {
                if (id && id !== lastsel) {
                    jQuery('#jqgrid').restoreRow(lastsel);
                    jQuery('#jqgrid').editRow(id, true);
                    lastsel = id;
                }
            },
            formatCell: function (rowid, cellname, value, iRow, iCol) {
                alert("before edit");
            },
            jsonReader: {
                repeatitems: false
            },
            rowNum: 20,
            rowList: [10, 20, 30],
            pager: '#jqpager',
            sortname: 'CurrecncyID',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            caption: "Prices List",
            autowidth: true,
            height: "100%",
            loadtext: "Loading...",
            editurl: "/handlers/myurl.ashx"
        });`
```

Comment: CurrecncyID is misspelled, also your should use a javascript debugger to have more information about your problem, the one in firefox works well.

Comment: Just to clarify, you can use a debugger such as Firebug in Firefox to track down problems such as this.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not it. the data source is also misspelled :)

Comment: I'm using IE9 Dev-toolbar no error is shown.

Answer (score 1):

There are three main [editing modes](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ajqgriddocs#editing) used in jqGrid. The [formatCell](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing#events) event is a part of the [cell editing mode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acell_editing). It will be not fire in case of usage of editRow and restoreRow are the part of the [inline editing mode](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3ainline_editing). Probably you need use [custom editable element](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#custom) in case of the usage of the inline editing mode.